# Macbook Pro 2018 13" wakes up with empty battery but is not actually empty

Tags: battery

Last week I had a few times that in the morning, after closing the lid (i.e. not shutting down) that when powering up (no power connected) I see a red empty battery icon.
Weird, as the night before it was about 70-80% full.
After connecting the power I saw it was really 1% but after a few minutes it showed 75%. I have experienced this just two times the past week. I did not install any updates the past two months (I am running Monterey 12.1).

Looking on the internet I saw that similar problems arose after an update to 12.2. But for me it appeared to be different:

- Bluetooth was OFF, so the mentioned BT problems do not apply.
- The battery was not drained at all, it was still 78-80% but some software bug faked it was empty ?
  I rebooted and checked whether BT is off which was the case.
  Showing `htop` did not show any hogging processes.

Hardware: MBP 2018 with 500GB HD and 16GB RAM.
No devices were connected via any ports.
Find attached the battery settings.

What is going on here ?

`pmset -g log | grep -w Charge` results in :

```
2022-02-18 21:37:30 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Idle Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:79%) 3060 secs 
2022-02-18 22:28:30 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to EC.LidClose/HID Activity Using BATT (Charge:79%) 14 secs   
2022-02-18 22:28:44 +0100 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:75%)           
2022-02-18 22:28:59 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:75%) 4115 secs 
2022-02-18 23:37:34 +0100 DarkWake            ###   DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.ARPT/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:75%) 45 secs   
2022-02-18 23:38:19 +0100 Sleep               ###   Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:75%) 3064 secs 
2022-02-19 00:29:23 +0100 DarkWake            ###   DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.SleepTimer/SleepTimer Using BATT (Charge:77%) 0 secs    
2022-02-19 00:29:23 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:77%) 27263 secs
2022-02-19 08:03:46 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Standby [CDNVA] : due to EC.USBC/UserActivity Assertion Using BATT (Charge:74%)           
2022-02-19 08:03:46 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 75)          
2022-02-19 08:23:23 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: BGTask] Using AC(Charge: 78)          
2022-02-19 08:23:58 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IPushSrvc kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 82)          
2022-02-19 09:02:54 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:99%) 1802 secs 
2022-02-19 09:32:56 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to EC.RTC/Maintenance Using AC (Charge:99%) 45 secs   
2022-02-19 09:33:06 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser PushSrvc SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 100)          
2022-02-19 09:33:41 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 100)          
2022-02-19 09:33:41 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 383 secs  
2022-02-19 09:40:04 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to EC.LidOpen/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)
```

The ### marked lines occurred when the Mac was closed without power connected and I was asleep so did not use it.
And `pmset -g log | grep -w Summary-` resulted in :

```
2022-02-18 20:10:16 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt(Charge: 87)          
2022-02-18 21:36:33 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 79)          
2022-02-18 21:37:00 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt(Charge: 79)          
2022-02-19 08:03:46 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 75)          
2022-02-19 08:23:17 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt          
2022-02-19 08:23:23 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: BGTask] Using AC(Charge: 78)          
2022-02-19 08:23:58 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IPushSrvc kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 82)          
2022-02-19 09:33:06 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser PushSrvc SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 100)          
2022-02-19 09:33:41 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 100)
```

Hence no sign of an empty battery.[image]

Comment: What's the battery cycle and condition? IME, erratic battery level indications are indicative of a failing battery.

Comment: Battery condition is not the problem, I checked it. I can use it for long without charger. So it is a pure software issue. When connected five minutes after being 'empty' it is over 80%.

Comment: After update to 12.2.1 (actually 10.17.2.1) occurred the problem was gone. So it was a bug in macOS.